# DataBricks Read Snowflake Returns Inconsistent Row Counts

Tags: python, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I'm attempting to read data from Snowflake into DataBricks. I want to read a whole table/view. Not push down a query. However the number of rows returned varies depending on the letter case of the strings I pass.

I'm running DBR 13.3 LTS with the DataBricks native Snowflake connector in Python.

In this code, the case of the strings represents the case of my arguments. The 'dbtable' argument is the unqualified (no Database or Schema) name of the object.

```
options = {
    'host': "my_host",
    'user': "my_user",
    'password': dbutils.secrets.get("my_scope", "my_secret"),
    'sfWarehouse':  "my_warehouse",
    'database': "MY_DATABASE",
    'schema': "MY_SCHEMA",
}

df_uppercase = spark.read.format('snowflake')\
    .options(**options)\
    .option('dbtable', 'MY_TABLE')\
    .load()

df_lowercase = spark.read.format('snowflake')\
    .options(**options)\
    .option('dbtable', 'my_table')\
    .load()

print(df_uppercase.count()) # returns 81,116,918
print(df_lowercase.count()) # returns 81,117,068
```

The lowercase argument form returns the correct result. The UPPERCASE one was truncated. This is validated by running...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_database.my_schema.my_table
-- returns 81,117,068
```

...in the Snowflake UI. In that context the result is consistent no matter what case I use.

I could force all my 'dbtable' arguments to use lowercase. But for different objects I've seen the inverse situation. The correct result is returned by the UPPERCASE form and incorrect returned by lowercase.

All objects referenced are views. There are no objects with the same names in different Databases or Schemas.

My questions:

- what is the correct form of arguments to guarantee that the connector returns all rows?
- why does the case matter?
- why is the significance of the case inconsistent?

Comment: Can you figure out if the missing rows have something in common? `rows_in_df1_not_in_df2 = df1.exceptAll(df2)`, after changing back case to match